# command for JSON-Feed does not get executed in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to fetch a `JSON-feed` but somehow the command is never executed. I have placed a `NSLog` just before the session gets called and that actually gets output on the console. The `NSLog` later "**test**" never gets output. I can't find out where the problem is. Another JSON request works just fine. Here is the code:

```
NSLog(@"fetchClassified started!");

// connect to webserver and ask for the feed

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.server/services/rest/v1/interface2?id=22"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// create a task that transfers the feed from the server
NSURLSessionTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                             NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                                options:0 error:nil];
                                                     NSLog(@"test %@", jsonObject);

                                                     self.classified = jsonObject[@"tasks"];
                                                     NSLog(@"%@", self.classified);

                                                     // put the output on the main queue (UI has to run always on main thread)
                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                         self.textView.text =self.classified;
                                                     });
                                                 }
                                  ];
[dataTask resume];
```

Thank you in advance for any hint on this!

Comment: The title of your question doesn't relate to the question itself, but anyway; have you checked that `self.session` is not `nil` at this point?

Comment: You are right, it was nil! NOw it enteres, but I get an exception after this:                                                        NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

Comment: What's the error that gets output to the console?

Comment: OK. Isolated the prob: NSLog(@"%@", self.classified); output: {   text = "the text";} Now how do I access the text?  NSLog(@"%@", self.classified[@"text"]); unfortunatelly does not work. There is only one classified in the feed with multiple attributes.

Answer (score 0):

JoeFryer solved it. self.session was nil.